# ViewPager of React Native is giving error 'View config not found for name RNCViewPager'

Tags: react-native, android-viewpager

I am trying to use a simple ViewPager on React native. I am facing a problem when I try to run the app on an emulator. (I have not tested it on IOS and I don't require to test it too.)

So, I have a very simple piece of code -

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager';

const ViewPager_3 = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ViewPager style={styles.viewPager} initialPage={0}>
        <View style={styles.page} key="1">
          <Text>First page</Text>
          <Text>Swipe ➡️</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.page} key="2">
          <Text>Second page</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.page} key="3">
          <Text>Third page</Text>
        </View>
      </ViewPager>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewPager: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  page: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default ViewPager_3;
```

When I try to run the code on Android emulator it gives an error on the page, find below--

```
Invariant Violation: View config not found for name RNCViewPager.

This error is located at:
    in RNCViewPager (at ViewPager.js:174)
    in ViewPager (at ViewPager_3.js:8)
    in RCTView (at ViewPager_3.js:7)
    in ViewPager_3 (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by Card)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (created by PanGestureHandler)
```

What could be the reason for the same?